Python ConnectionRefusedError using a Docker compose with jupyter notebook and spring boot
I wrote a local application using spring boot in which I have three containers: mongodb, mongo-express and jupyter noteboot. Using a python script I can access the data without errors
import requests
import json

url = "http://localhost:8080/api/v1/metadata/sites"

response = requests.get(url)
print(response)

# print json content
print(response.json())

>>> <Response [200]>

However, when I repeat the same code in the notebook (of the container) I get this error

FROM python:3.9
LABEL authors=""

# Install any necessary packages
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    build-essential \
    git && \
    apt-get clean && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Set the working directory
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the requirements file and install the dependencies
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
#RUN pip install --no-cache-dir jupyterlab numpy==1.26.4 && \
#    pandas==2.2.2 && \
#    requests==2.31.0
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir numpy==1.26.4  \
    jupyter \
    pandas==2.2.2 \
    requests==2.31.0

# Copy the notebooks to the container
COPY . /app

EXPOSE 8888

# Set the default command to run Jupyter Notebook
CMD ["jupyter", "notebook", "--ip=0.0.0.0", "--port=8888", "--no-browser", "--allow-root", "--NotebookApp.token=''"]




version: '3.9'

services:
  # Database - Mongo DB
  mongodb:
    image: mongo:latest
    container_name: mongodb
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    env_file: .env
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=${MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME}
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=${MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD}
      - MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE=${MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE}
    volumes:
      # - data:/data
      - mongo-volume:/data/db2
      - ./mongo-init.js:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/mongo-init.js:ro
      # - mongo-data:/data/db

  # Database Manager
  mongo-express:
    image: mongo-express:latest
    container_name: mongo-express
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    depends_on:
      - mongodb
    env_file: .env
    environment:
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME=${ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME}
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD=${ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD}
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER=mongodb # same name of "mongodb" in services


  jupyter:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./jupyter/Dockerfile
    container_name: jupyter-metadata-itineris
    ports:
      - '8888:8888'
    volumes:
      - ./notebooks:/app

# Define named volumes
volumes:
  mongo-volume: {}

networks:
  default:
    name: mongodb_network


Did you try 127.0.0.1 in the notebook instead of localhost?

yes. Right now,  I tried url = "http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/v1/metadata/sites" but with the same error
